# Mongoose async requests managment

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I'm actually trying to convert mongodb references into those references' documents value (info.value) using mongoose in javascript.

Tried that by using map, for/forEach, and nothing did the job since mongoose requests are async.

Not really used to this kind of code, I feel a bit lost after all those things I tried.

Maybe someone would like to give me a hint about this by taking a look at the code below.

Just for information, no need to worry about loading templates, connecting to mongo, ... since everything else is working just fine.

That's the closest I got to the expected result, but still, it throws me errors when I try to "**console.log(cond[c]);/console.log(info);**" (cond[c] and info are null and undefined)

Well this function also needs to be prepared to be recursive since I plan to put sub-blocks in the "content" property of the bloc objects.

Thanks a lot for your time guys.

```
// Input condition
"H1Vf3KTef || false"

// Expected result
"1 || false"

// Buggy Function
var execIfBlock = function recursExec (query, callback) {
  IfBlockModel.findOne(query, function(err, ifBlock) {
    if (!err) {
      var cond = ifBlock.condition.split(" ");
      //console.log('Block : ' + ifBlock);
      //console.log('Condition : ' + cond);
      var calls = new Array();
      for (var c = 0, len = cond.length; c < len; c++) {
        if (shortId.isValid(cond[c])) {
          calls.push(function() {
            InfoModel.findOne({ _id: cond[c] }, function(err, info) {
              console.log(cond[c]);
              console.log(info);
              cond[c] = info.value;
            });
          });
        }
      }
      async.parallel(calls, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        // Do some job using the final expected result : "1 || false"
      });
    }
  });
};

// Info template
{
  "_id": "H1Vf3KTef",
  "value": "1"
}

// Bloc template
{
  "_id": "rkRBtLTef",
  "content": [],
  "condition": "H1Vf3KTef || false"
}

// Info schema
var InfoSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, default: shortId.generate },
  value: { type: String, default: "0" }
});

// Bloc schema
var IfBlockSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, default: shortId.generate },
  condition: { type: String, required: true, default: true },
  content: [{ type: String, required: true, default: '', ref: 'block' }]
});
```

Comment: Can you use new Node.js or are you stuck with some old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use promises and break your code in small functions :

```
var execIfBlock = function recursExec(query, callback) {
    IfBlockModel.findOne(query, function (err, ifBlock) {
        if (!err) {
            var cond = ifBlock.condition.split(" ");

            updateMultipeInfo(cond)
                .then(values => {
                    console.log(values) // [values1, values ,...]
                });
        }
    });
};


function updateMultipeInfo(cond){
    return Promise.all(cond.map(updateInfo))
}

function updateInfo(id){
    if (shortId.isValid(id)) {
        return InfoModel
            .findOne({ _id: id })
            .then(info => info.value);
    } else {
        return Promise.reject("invalid id");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, Thank you so much !